# If string exists in a row, return the column NAME under which the string exists in a new column

Tags: r, stringr, grepl

I have a data frame like this with some text/descriptions:

````
Year       Descr1              Descr2             Descr3
2017    Abby is cool        Hi, call me 5      Don't call    
1997    Is Doug cool?       Is Gideon OK?     Abby's coming at 5 
2020     Hi i'm Gideon       Hi i'm Abby       OK, ttyl   

My keywords are Doug and Abby. If any of my keywords appear in a row, I want a new column that tells me the column name. See below

```    FY        Descr1            Descr2           Descr3         Found_in
      2017    Abby is cool        Hi call me      Don't call        Descr1
      1997    Is Doug cool?       Abby's coming  Is Gideon OK?      Descr1, Descr2
      2020    Hi i'm Gideon       OK, ttyl       Hi i'm Abby        Descr3    ```

right now I have:
````

````
df$Found_in <- ifelse(grepl(keywords,df[,1], ignore.case=TRUE), "Descr1",
           ifelse(grepl(keywords,df[,2], ignore.case=TRUE), "Descr2",
           ifelse(grepl(keywords,df[,3], ignore.case=TRUE), "Descr3", "NA")))    ```
````

But I have a pretty large data frame so I was wondering if there is a way to search for my keywords and if they exist anywhere in my data frame, return the col name under which they exist.

I hope this question makes sense. Also please forgive the format, this is my first time asking a question on here.

Comment: What if they appear in multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could address the issue (I will use your first data and a solution to avoid `ifelse`) but some considerations must be made about the strings (For example they could be transformed tolower so that is more easy to implement this kind of comparisons):

```
#Data
data <- structure(list(Year = c(2017, 1997, 2020), Descr1 = c("Abby is cool", 
"Is Doug cool?", "Hi i'm Gideon"), Descr2 = c("Hi, call me 5", 
"Is Gideon OK?", "Hi i'm Abby"), Descr3 = c("Don't call", "Abby's coming at 5", 
"OK, ttyl")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

#Code
data$Index <- apply(data[,-1],1,function(x) paste(names(x)[which(grepl(pattern = c('Doug|Abby'),x = x))],collapse=','))
```

It produces:

```
  Year        Descr1        Descr2             Descr3         Index
1 2017  Abby is cool Hi, call me 5         Don't call        Descr1
2 1997 Is Doug cool? Is Gideon OK? Abby's coming at 5 Descr1,Descr3
3 2020 Hi i'm Gideon   Hi i'm Abby           OK, ttyl        Descr2
```

Comment: Changing to `grepl(pattern = c('Doug|Abby'),x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)` will avoid having to add a `tolower` if needed

Comment: @Duck, and Chuck P,  I cannot thank you both enough!!! This works perfectly. One quick question: how do I get "NA" instead of blanks for rows where string doesn't exist?